# Passing flash variables to asp.net

Tags: asp.net, flash

I don't know much about Flash but we are working on a site that has a flash form and when the users pick an option, like selecting a value from a drop down list, we need the value to be passed to asp.net server-side code. What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Flash can invoke server side service. So use GET or POST to pass data

Answer (score 0):

You could explore these options:

1) Communicate between the SWF and the containing page through JavaScript

2) Communicate via asp.net webservices from the SWF directly to the webservice.

3) Not sure but could probably do a POST to a processing aspx page?

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I think a good option is to use the XML class so consider this:

```
var xmlRequest = new XML();
xmlRequest.onLoad = parseXMLResponse;
xmlRequest.load("http://yourpathtoyourserver/file.aspx?listselectedvalue=something");

function parseXMLRequest(loaded)
{
  trace("hi");
}
```

You can also have the page give you data back this way so it's not just one way communication.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Action Script 2.

Read the important notes at the bottom of each codes pertain to sending and retrieving data from flash to .net page. Explanation of the code is in the comment inside the code.

**Flash Part (Action Script 2)**

```
//function to send collected form data to asp.net page
//use other control/button to call this function
//important: in order for the 'onLoad' event to work correctly, this function has to be 'Void'
function sendForm():Void
{
    //create LoadVars object
    var lv_in:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
    var lv_out:LoadVars = new LoadVars();

    //set onLoad event
    lv_in.onLoad = function(success:Boolean)
    {
        //if success, meaning data has received from .net page, run this code
        if (success)
        {
        //lv_in.status is use to get the posted data from .Net page
            statusMsg.text = "Thank you for filling up the form!" + lv_in.status;
        }
        //if fail, run this code
        else
        {
            statusMsg.text = "The form you are trying to fill up has an error!";
        }
    }

    //this is the collected data from the form
    lv_out.userName = txtUserName.text;
    lv_out.userAddress = txtUserAddress.text;
    lv_out.userBirthday = txtUserBirthday.text;

    //begin invoke .net page
    lv_out.sendAndLoad("ProcessDataForm.aspx", lv_in, "POST");
}
```

**Important note:**
The function that contain **onLoad** event, in this case **sendForm** function, has to be **Void** function, meaning it's not returning value. If this function return value, what happen is the function will be executed all the way without waiting for the returned data from .net page, thus the **onLoad** event will not be set properly.

**.Net Part**

```
public void ProcessData
{
    //process the data here

    Response.Write("status=processed&");
}
```

**Important note:**
To send data/message back to flash, you can use **Response.Write**. However, if you want Action Script to parse the posted message/data from .Net page keep in mind you have to include **&** symbol at the end of the message. When parsing data/message, Action Script will stop at **&** symbol, thus leave the rest of the message alone and only get the message under *sent* variable.